# Extract numbers with awk

Tags: bash, grep, awk

a part of a script in awk looks like this

```
sub(/^Mutation: {"seq-pos":/,"") && sub(/, "time":/," ") && sub(/}$/,"") { print >"fifth_"FILENAME}
```

The aim is that given this input:

```
Mutation: {"seq-pos":0.00030804, "time":0, 0.164494, 1.00723}
Mutation: {"seq-pos":0.176236, "time":0.31516, 0.6876, 1.00723}
Mutation: {"seq-pos":0.224808, "time":0, 0.813626, 1.00723}
```

I can get the following output:

```
0.00030804 0  0.164494  1.00723
0.17623 0.31516 0.6876 1.00723
0.224808 0 0.813626 1.00723
```

the code works if there is only 1 number after it. How would I need to mod

the whole script ...

```
!body && /^\/\/$/              {body=1}
body  && sub(/^gthcont: */,"") {print > "second_"FILENAME}
body  && /^[01]+/              {print > "third_"FILENAME}
body  && /^\[[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\]/ {
    print > "first_"FILENAME
    print substr($0, 2, index($0,"]")-2) > "fourth_"FILENAME
}
sub(/^Mutation: {"seq-pos":/,"") && sub(/, "time":/," ") && sub(/}$/,"") { print >"fifth_"FILENAME}
```

ify?

Comment: `tr -cd "0-9 \n." < file`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest defining multiple field separators (i.e. `:`, `,`, and `}`) and then select the fields accordingly:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[:,}]" } { print $3,$5,$6,$7 } '
```

Answer (score 1):

What about removing everything not being a digit, a dot or a space?

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[^0-9. ]/,"")}1' file
 0.00030804 0 0.164494 1.00723
 0.176236 0.31516 0.6876 1.00723
 0.224808 0 0.813626 1.00723
```

Note however that parsing a JSON with `awk` is not a very good approach. You may want to use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) for this.

Comment: how would I do it in the way asa shown with the sub as in the original scrip...because it is part of a larger scriot...

Comment: Just replace all the `sub ()` parts and place this. And keep the `print` while removing the `1` in my script.

Comment: but the whole file is also larger ...i edited and show the while script...

Comment: @kagh then clarify what you are looking forward. It is also useful to learn a bit about `awk` before trying to change a script. Otherwise you will end up asking a question for every single step.

Comment: so a file is split into a ser of subfile only a couple of lines start with Mutat...only in these m the fifth file (last lin) is used..

Comment: @kagh then say `awk '/^Mutation/ {gsub(/[^0-9. ]/,""); print >"fifth_"FILENAME}' file`

Comment: with the sub aroun dit or how..sorry could you expl@?

Comment: @kagh just replace `sub(/^Mutation: {"seq-pos":/,"") && sub(/, "time":/," ") && sub(/}$/,"") { print >"fifth_"FILENAME}` with the line I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: but the scrip is already awk..why mentio awk in a awk scrip..shoudl it  be body?

Comment: @kagh of course, you just need the code within the single quotes. `/^Mutation/ {gsub(/[^0-9. ]/,""); print >"fifth_"FILENAME}`.